# BD connection in __construct method

Tags: php, mysql, laragon

```
public function __construct($_mobile= array()){
        $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die("not connected");
        mysql_select_db("oop_crud") or die("db not found");
        echo "testing";
}
```

Comment: You're mixing APIs. `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` are two different things.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)

Comment: Please describe the problem, what you expect to be done and what happens.  Don't expect people guess your intention or run your code.